# Single Makefile to build both main.c and main.cpp

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make, c11

I would like to `make main-c` to build `main-c` from `main.c`.

And `make main-cpp` to build `main-cpp` from `main.cpp`.

I have, all in the same folder:

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("This ic C\n");
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "This is C++" << std::endl;
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS   = -std=gnu11

CXXFLAGS = -std=gnu++11 

CPPFLAGS = -g -Wall -O3
LDFLAGS  = 
LDLIBS   =  
OBJS     = main.o 

APP-C    = main-c
APP-CPP  = main-cpp

default:
    echo "Check README.txt"

main-c: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

main-cpp: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -Rf *.o 

distclean: clean
    -rm -Rf $(APP-C) $(APP-CPP)
```

So:

```
$ make main-c
cc -std=gnu11 -g -Wall -O3  -c -o main.o main.c
cc main.o  -o main-c
```

But (also builds from `.c`):

```
$ make main-cpp
cc -std=gnu11 -g -Wall -O3  -c -o main.o main.c
c++ main.o  -o main-cpp
```

I was expecting `make main-cpp` to use `$(CXX) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@` and build from `.cpp`. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't torture yourself. Rename your source files to files with unique _root_ names (e.g.) `main-cpp.cpp` and `main-c.c` and adjust dependencies accordingly (e.g.: `main-cpp: main-cpp.o` and `main-c: main-c.o`). Or spell out all rules explicitly (per vu1p3n0x). But, even if you could get it to work, IMO, having `main.c` and `main.cpp` in the same directory is confusing to humans and `make` and should be avoided if possible

Comment: `make main-cpp --debug` will help you see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting make main-cpp to use $(CXX) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@ and build from .cpp.

It is. `make main-cpp --debug` will help you see what is going on.

The problem is you are relying on the default rule for making the `main.o` needed by both `main-cpp` and `main-c` target, but you want a different build when `make-cpp` target is invoked. In this case you'll need to define different non default rules to build the .o files. It's easiest if you just make `make-cpp` and `main-c` depend on a .o with a different name. Since they are different builds they should have different names anyway:

```
CFLAGS   = -std=gnu11
CXXFLAGS = -std=gnu++11 
CPPFLAGS = -g -Wall -O3
LDFLAGS  = 
LDLIBS   =  
APP-C   = main-c
APP-CPP  = main-cpp

default:
    echo "Check README.txt"

main-c: %:%.o
    $(CC) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

main-cpp: %:%.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

main-cpp.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $? -o $@

main-c.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $? -o $@

clean:
    -rm -Rf *.o 

distclean: clean
    -rm -Rf $(APP-C) $(APP-CPP)
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `%` and `%:%`?

Comment: It's a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html). There is not much point using it here because the is only one target. It just equates to `main-c: main-c.o` in the above case.

Comment: @spinkus: may I suggest that you remove the static patter rules from your answer? They are not needed here and make your proposal uselessly difficult to understand.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet easily understood once you've seen it once. Useful shorthand to know when want to update script later. Example you could just use g++  in the two linking targets and combine to one rule since it is just linking.

Answer (score 0):

Both rules, `main-c` and `main-cpp`, require `main.o` to be created to complete, but you don't have a rule for creating `main.o`.

You're using [make's implicit object file creation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) which is a built-in rule for creating a '.o' file from a source file. It can use either a '.c' or '.cpp/cc/C' file and will build using the appropriate variables. However, since you have both `main.c` and `main.cpp`, it looks like it defaults to using the C version.

You'd probably need to create explicit rules (and probably use different names) for each one.